# A question regarding a central idempotent in a ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to solve the problem:

> *Question:* In a ring $R$ with identity, if every idempotent is central, then prove that for $a, b \in R$, $$ab =1 \implies ba=1$$

I have done in the following manner:
$$ab=1\\
\implies b(ab)=b\\
\implies (ba)b-b=0\\
\implies (ba-1)b=0$$

Case 1: If $R$ contains no divisor of Zero then as $b \ne 0$ ,we get $$ba-1=0 \implies ba=1$$

Case 2: If $R$ contains divisor of Zeros then we may have $$ba-1\ne0\\
\implies ba\ne1\\
\implies (ab)a\ne a$$
But $ab=1$ hence $a\ne a$, an absurd condition. So $ba-1=0$ or $ba=1$.

I think I have solved the problem but I haven't used the given conditions "Every idempotent is central". So I think there is something wrong which I have done but can't find out! Please rectify my mistake if I am wrong and provide any hint to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps every idempotent is central in every ring with identity?

Comment: Your mistake is concluding that $ba \neq 1$ implies $(ab)a \neq a$. As for a hint: Show that if $ab = 1$ then $(1 - ba)$ is an idempotent.

Comment: @RobertFrost in Reduced Ring every idempotent is central

Comment: $(1-ba)$ is idempotent,I get it and hence $a(1-ba)=(1-ba)a$ $=>a-(ab)a=a-(ba)a$ $=>0=a-a(ba)$ $=>0=a-(ab)a$ $=>a=(ab)a$..........I think we cann't obtain such result if we multiply to both side if LHS and RHS are different in arbitarary Rings.That's the reason for my wrong conclusion $(ab)a$ $\ne$ $a$.Isn't it?@AlexZorn

Comment: @RobertFrost if $a$ is a devisor of zero then $\exists$ $b$ $\ne$ $0$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$ though $b$ $\ne$ $0$ we get eual LHS and RHS if we multiply bothside by $a$

Comment: @RobertFrost *Perhaps every idempotent is central in every ring with identity?* Consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's kind of a slick solution (don't read further if you want to figure it out for yourself!)

$$ab = 1$$
$$\Longrightarrow (ba)^{2} = b(ab)a = ba$$

So $ba$ is an idempotent and therefore central. So we have:

$$b(ba) = (ba)b$$
$$\Rightarrow ab(ba) = a(ba)b$$
$$\Rightarrow (ab)(ba) = (ab)(ab)$$
$$\Rightarrow ba = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, $ba\neq 1$ does not imply $aba\neq a$. In rings for which there exists $ab=1$ and $ba\neq 1$ ([see here for examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917154/29335)) you have obviously that $aba=(ab)a=a$.

But clearly, if $ab=1$, $ba$ is at least idempotent, hence central by your hypotheses.

Then

$ba=(ba)ab =a(ba)b=abab =1$.